# Matplotlib Histogram Bins Include/Exclude

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code produces a histogram with only two bins. I was hoping for 3.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [9, 10, 11]
binwidth = 1
bins = np.arange(min(data), max(data) + binwidth, binwidth)
print(bins)
plt.title("A Rich Man Walks into a Bar")
plt.hist(data, bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But `bins` is `[ 9 10 11]` - so two bins. Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: I'm probably very confused. Perhaps I should be using a bar chart. I wanted a bar for each value. Is this possible with a histogram?

Comment: But `data` represents either the x- or the y-value. What represents the other value in your bar chart?

Comment: Like @Mr.T your `bins` are not the bin centers but the bin edges. So you have two bins, one with left edge 9 and right edge 10, and one with left edge 10 and right edge 11. See [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html)

Comment: To get nice bins for discrete data, you could put the 4 bin edges exactly between the values: `bins = np.arange(min(data) - binwidth/2, max(data) + binwidth, binwidth)`.  Note that seaborn's `histplot` and `countplot` do this type of settings more automatic for discrete data.

Answer (score 0):

`bins` argument defines either the number of bins or the bin edges. If you want to create a histogram with `n` bins, then the list `bins` defining the bin edges  has a size of `n+1`. So here we want the bin edges to be `[9, 10, 11, 12]` (if `align='left'`; or `[8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5]` if `align = 'mid'`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [9, 9, 11, 10, 9, 11, 11, 9]
width = 1
left, right = min(data), max(data) + width

# using 'bins' as the number of bins 
nbins = int((right - left) / width)
plt.hist(data, range=(left, right), bins=nbins, align="left")

# defining the sequence of bin edges
plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(left, right + width, width), align="left")

# and without the alignment parameter
plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(left, right + width, width) - width / 2)

# if 'data' only contains integers and 'width=1'
plt.bar(*np.unique(data, return_counts=True))
```